# subprocess.CalledProcessError: returned non-zero exit status 1 for non-pingable destination

Tags: python, linux

I am writing a `python` script to calculate *packet loss* through *ping* an `IP` address using `subprocess` module in linux. More than one IP address kept in `CSV` file. It is running fine when the pingable destination are only given.
But throwing an error when the non-pingable `IP` given in the `CSV` file and then the script is exiting without checking the other IP address in that `CSV` file. So I am not able to capture the *packet loss* for the non-pingable destination which is the main purpose the script.

Please suggest a way forward.

```
subprocess.check_output(['ping','-c 4',hostname], shell=False, 
universal_newlines=True).splitlines()

subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ping', '-c 4', '192.168.134.100']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Answer (score 2):

It is just that subprocess returns an error if your ping has 100% packet loss, destination unreachable or any other problem. What you could do is:

```
try:
    # subprocess code here
except:
    # some code here if the destination is not pingable, e.g. print("Destination unreachable..") or something else
    pass # You need pass so the script will continue on even after the error
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this Code:

```
import subprocess
def systemCommand(Command):
    Output = ""
    Error = ""     
    try:
        Output = subprocess.check_output(Command,stderr = subprocess.STDOUT,shell='True')
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        #Invalid command raises this exception
        Error =  e.output 

    if Output:
        Stdout = Output.split("\n")
    else:
        Stdout = []
    if Error:
        Stderr = Error.split("\n")
    else:
        Stderr = []

    return (Stdout,Stderr)

#in main
Host = "ip to ping"
NoOfPackets = 2
Timeout = 5000 #in milliseconds
#Command for windows
Command = 'ping -n {0} -w {1} {2}'.format(NoOfPackets,Timeout,Host)
#Command for linux 
#Command = 'ping -c {0} -w {1} {2}'.format(NoOfPackets,Timeout,Host)
Stdout,Stderr = systemCommand(Command)
if Stdout:
   print("Host [{}] is reachable.".format(Host))
else:
   print("Host [{}] is unreachable.".format(Host))
```